# what is load-store communication model in PCIe?

Tags: pcie

i have read PCIe follows the same load-store communication model as PCI but i am not clear about that model.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note it's not a free personal tutorial site or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and your own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: @Lalith, it would be great if you could write a paragraph of what you know and where your understanding is incomplete. Also ask a question in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

A load-store model for PCIe means that the primary transactions which can be expressed over a PCIe link are *loads*, or reads of memory addresses, and *stores*, or writes to memory addresses. The PCIe bus also indicates the use of interrupts, which can be transmitted out of band on a dedicated pin, or in-band using [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts) which itself uses loads and stores to addresses that cause interrupt behavior to fire.

On a modern-day computer with a PCIe bus, the physical memory address space is divided up among the system memory (i.e. the DRAM behind a memory controller) and peripherals, each of which has some [memory mappings expressed as configuration in Base Address Registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901221/pci-express-bar-memory-mapping-basic-understanding). Reads and writes into this memory region can be initiated by the processor (e.g. x86 MOVs that indicate memory locations, ARM ldr and str), by a DMA unit, or by another peripheral that initiates a PCIe transaction.

For example, let's consider a hypothetical PCIe card mapped at 0x7fa0000 - 0x7faffff with a function of providing 32 GPIO pins.

For example, reading *physical* address 0x7fa0000 could let the CPU fetch the current pin inputs, and writing to that address would set any outputs. Likewise, the card could be designed such that writes to another address (e.g. 0x7fa0004) are used to set pins to input and output modes. Perhaps another address of our hypothetical GPIO card allows software to map a pin to an interrupt - here, the CPU would initiate stores to configure the interrupt behavior, and the hypothetical GPIO card would initiate stores to specific addresses on the system interrupt controller to actually cause interrupts to fire.

The important thing is that all of these interactions occur as memory *loads* and *stores*, rather than another paradigm.